# Why my image is not width 100% only sur iphone?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i had a picture on a row in a width 100%. On android and desktop the website is completly responsive but on iphone the image is not homothétique like if the width 100% was not on the css.
This is a web app. Also the page online :https://tipourboire.com/faq/#serveur

Android :

[image]

iOS:
[image]

my html :

```
 <Row id='client'className='backgroundClient'><img src="/images/bandeauClient.png" /></Row>
       <Row>
    <Col className="paraClientFaq" xs={12} s={12} md={12}><h1><strong>Clients :</strong>{''}une nouvelle façon de remercier !</h1></Col>
           <Col className="paraClientTexteFaq" xs={12} s={12} md={12}><p>Vous avez de - en - de monnaie dans vos poches et la COVID-19 ne vous incite pas à en avoir ! Les restaurateurs n'acceptent que très rarement l'arrondi de l'addition sur le TPE ! Scannez le QR code Tipourboire présent sur votre addition, et donnez le montant de votre choix! Rapide, efficace et sécurisé sans être obligé de vous inscrire, vous aurez la garantie que votre pourboire digital arrivera à votre serveur ou encore à toute l'équipe si vous le desirez !</p></Col>
       </Row>
       <Row className="rowIconeClient">
           
           <Col md={2} s={6} xs={4} className="blocClient"><img className='img1' src="/images/greeting.png" /></Col>
           <Col md={2} s={6} xs={4}  className="blocClient"><img className='img2' src="/images/approved.png" /></Col>
           <Col md={2} s={6} xs={4}  className="blocClient"><img className='img3'src="/images/pouce.png" /></Col>
       </Row>
```

and css :

```
.FAQ .paraClientFaq{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f5a624;
}

.FAQ .paraClientTexteFaq{
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right:15%;
    font-size: 22px;
}


.FAQ .blocClient img{
    width:100%
}

.FAQ .rowIconeClient{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;

}

.FAQ .paraIcone{
    color: white;
    margin-top:7%;
}

.FAQ .backgroundClient img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please try using css property `object-fit` with multiple values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the CSS property `object.fit: contain` on the image.

The object-fit property allows you to have control on how the image is displayed based on the screen size.

I have checked your link and tested this solution on Chrome and FF:

```
.FAQ .backgroundClient img{
    width:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

alternatively, you can set the max-width to 100% (meaning the image will not resize over 100%) with `height` set to `auto`:

```
.FAQ .backgroundClient img{
        max-width:100%;
        height: auto;
 }
```

[image]

if this answer helps you solving the issue, **consider** upvoting it or accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: it's working on the simulator but not on the real iphone

Comment: did you set the `.FAQ .backgroundClient img` to `object-fit: contain` ? see edited answer.

Comment: yes i tried contain and cover. It's not responsive too when i put the website online :/

Comment: did you try the second option, max-width 100% and height auto? without the object-fit property?

Comment: @rag2riches yes i just tried and it doesn't change anything

Comment: OK, please do this: 1) remove the CSS for `.FAQ .backgroundClient img` completely. 2) set an ID attribute in your HTML doc for that image, say  id = image1. 3) set the CSS for image1 equal to `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto`. Test it and let me know. If successful, it is likely that your CSS breaks somewhere or previous CSS selectors override that class. Try to structure your CSS using BOM

Comment: @rag2riches ijust put the picture on background:url and it's working ! thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try giving your img a style; object-fit: contain;

Comment: it doesn't work, change nothing on android and desktop but doesn't work on iOS